# How to use other colomn sum in jqgrid grouping?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, grouping

In jqgrid grouping we can use summaryType : 'sum' and get sum of the group. Then I just want to use that sum for the calculation of another column summery by using summaryType : mysum() function. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithGroupingAndCustomFormatter_.htm) created for [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7622718/315935). It contains an example of implementation `summaryType` as function. The demo demonstrate additionally custom formatter of the summary row which you probably don't need.

Comment: @Oleg thanks for the reply. what I need is to take a sum of some column and use that sum in a function called a by different column. As a example think I want to find a average by (Sum of the column1)/(Sum of the colomn2) and display as summery of average column.Can I do it ?