# Put specific data in jqgrid summary view header

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a working jqgrid table that has summary view on the header, just like this example that I implemented in this this plunkr here http://plnkr.co/edit/wjIlaVMsa9vusmfhgfL1?p=preview.

The summary view header works fine, and the data displayed comes from (sum) function in the jqgrid.

However, instead of letting the jqgrid calculate the summary by itself, I want to display my own data in the summary row (and still per column, I dont want a colspan summary header). Easiest example will be: suppose the data under my columns are all text. I still want to have grouping & summary view header & show data per column on the summary header, but I don't want jqgrid to calculate the summary for me (since it's a text). I want to display my own summary data, which comes also from my data json.

I dont think using

```
summaryTpl: '<b>{0}<b>'
```

will work for me since the data that I want to display comes from my json data.

Is this possible?
Let me know if my explanation is not clear enough. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The demo which you posted uses jqGrid 4.6 version. You have not so much possibility to set custom summary value in the case. You can use custom formatter in the column where you need to place custom summary value. I described the approach in [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7622718/315935). It's really tricky.

Alternatively I can suggest you to use [free jqGrid 4.8](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (see [readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md) and [wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki)). Free jqGrid supports `summaryType` defined as function. To show how it works I created some JSFiddle examples for you. [The first one](http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/78m7jdaz/) consist from your original demo. [The second one](http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/78m7jdaz/1/) contains

```
summaryType: function (v, cn, record) {
    var fieldData = parseInt(record[cn], 10);
    return v === "" ? fieldData : fieldData + v; 
}
```

instead of `summaryType: "sum"`. The results in summary column will be close to the original one, but I used `parseInt(record[cn], 10)` instead of `parseFloat(record[cn])`. So I get only integer part of the input numbers and the results will be integer too.

[The next demo](http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/78m7jdaz/2/) contains static variable

```
var mySummary = {
    ALFKI: 12,
    ANATR: 23,
    AROUT: 34,
    BERGS: 45,
    BLAUS: 56
};
```

and the `summaryType` which looks as

```
summaryType: function (v, cn, record) {
    return mySummary[record.CustomerID];
}
```

In the way the summary results for every group will be displayed based on the `mySummary` map. I remind you that the values will be formatted by the same formatter which you defined in the column. Because you use `formatter: 'number'` in the column `Freight`, then the results should be numbers or the string which can be converted to numbers.

[The last demo](http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/78m7jdaz/3/) uses modified JSON data

```
{
    "userdata": {
        "ALFKI": 12.34,
        "ANATR": 23.45,
        "AROUT": 34.56,
        "BERGS": 45.67,
        "BLAUS": 56.78
    },
    "rows":[
        ....
    ]
}
```

The `summaryType` I defined so

```
summaryType: function (v, cn, record) {
    var userData = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "userData");
    return userData[record.CustomerID];
}
```

As the result the values displayed in the grouping summary come from the `userdata` part of the server. I think it's what you want.

Comment: hi Oleg, thanks for the reply! Is the technique mentioned in free jqGrid 4.8 supported in jqGrid 4.8 (http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1467) ? I am only allowed to use jqGrid and not other forked library..

Comment: @blenzcoffee: You are welcome! You should test it yourself, whether it's supported by Guriddo jqGrid JavaScript 4.8... There are no more jqGrid. You can ask on [Grriddo forum](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=4).

Comment: No more jqGrid? Do you mean the last version is jqGrid 4.8? (I'll check the forum). I'm trying your answer now. I already have my user data when I'm setting the jqGrid options, so I'm going with the static variable way. I'll see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: @blenzcoffee: You are welcome! You can ask on [Grriddo forum](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=4) if you purchased the product.

Comment: hi Oleg, turns out jqGrid 4.6.0 supports summaryType as function too :) so I used the technique described in your old answer. thank you very much! this is very, very helpful!