# Jqgrid - Validation on selecting dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

i have this column with dropdown, currently when i select any value from the dropdown it it gets saved, i would like to add a validation while selecting a value from dropdown before saving, for example,

```
{name:'color_name',
    cellattr: function (rowid, cellValue) {
    if ($.inArray(cellValue, hilightcolorcell) < 0) {
    return " class='redcells'";
    }
    },editable:true,edittype:"select",editoptions:
    {value:"PURPLE:PURPLE;PINK:PINK;GREEN:GREEN"}}
```

if the selected value was PINK, i wanted to have a validation prompt with Save and Cancel button something like this, Selected Value is : PINK, SAVE CANCEL

this is demo link https://jsfiddle.net/kwu7v3fc/3/

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to implement your requirement. The most native would seems to me to ask the confirmation from the user directly on change of the select option and *before* real saving it. One can add "change" event handler, which do all you need. The corresponding implementation will look like on the example below

```
editoptions: {
    value: "PURPLE:PURPLE;PINK:PINK;GREEN:GREEN",
    dataEvents: [
        {
            type: "change",
            fn: function (e) {
                if ($(this).val() === "PINK") {
                    if (!confirm("Are you sure you want PINK?")) {
                        // reset the value to the previous one
                        var savedRow = $("#rowed5").jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");
                        $(this).val(savedRow[0].v);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

See the modified demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/kwu7v3fc/5/

Comment: thank you sir, one doubt, if we want to display the actual cell value and selected value, how to achive? for example, the actual value was Pink and the dropdown selected value was PINK, how to prompt "Are you sure you want to change Pink to PINK ?"

Comment: @davidb: You are welcome! `savedRow[0].v` is the value in the cell before the editing was started. The value `$(this).val()` is the value of the currently chosen option. You can replace `"Are you sure you want PINK?"` to `"Are you sure you want to change " + savedRow[0].v + " to " + $(this).val() +  "?"`. You need of cause to move `$("#rowed5").jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow")` above to initialize `savedRow` before the usage. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/kwu7v3fc/6/